# React.js/Redux: setInterval and clearInterval in Reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, setinterval, react-redux, reducers

Currently I am working on [FCC Game of Life](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-the-game-of-life) and I was able figure out how to generate the next app state (incrementally).

That being said, my next step is to figure out how to generate new app state (generation) continuously. In this case, I am trying to implement setInterval and clearInterval inside my **reducer**.

I'd like to have the ability to start/pause generating new generation (by toggling the state in **state.start**)

The thing I am having trouble of implementing it is the scope issue.

Here's part my reducer:

**reducers/reducers_grid.js**

```
export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    ....
    case START:
      let toggleStart = state.start === true ? false : true;

      if (state.start === true){
        console.log('START THE GAME')

        const newGeneration = nextGeneration(action.payload,state)
        return Object.assign({}, state, {cells: newGeneration, start: toggleStart })
      }
      else {
        console.log('PAUSE THE GAME')
        return Object.assign({}, state, {start: toggleStart })
      }

  return state;
}
```

Essentially, **nextGeneration function** results the new app state (generation) and updates it to via Object.assign

At first, I thought putting **setInteveral** inside the first if statement and **clearInterval** in the second if statement, but obviously that will create a scope issue.

It seems very trivial this part of logic, but I've been stuck on this awhile.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't do this in the reducer. Reducers should be pure functions (meaning no side-effects). Instead, you could create a component that is rendered only when the game is running (a boolean state which is set to `true` by the `START` action and `false` by the `STOP` action). Then in the component's `componentDidMount` function call `setInterval` with a function that dispatches a `NEXT_GENERATION` action. After that dispatch another action which adds the timer id to the store. Then, in the `componentWillUnmount` call `clearInterval` with the timer id.